# How to work with resource dlls without WinAPI in C#?

Tags: c#, dll, resources, portability

I have a C# application that loads resources from dlls (these dlls contain only resources, no any code). For working with resources it uses `WinAPI` functions like `LoadLibrary()`, `FindResource()`, etc.

But I want to make it portable into other operating systems (OS X, Linux, iOS, Android, WP). Obviously, these operating systems don't have `KERNEL32.DLL` or `USER32.DLL`. So is there any alternatives for `WinAPI` usage that are written on pure C# and so will work on other platforms?

Comment: Why you don't use .Net libraries to store resources? What is the goal? Localization?

Comment: libraries are not mine and I don't have their sources @YohDeadfall

Comment: Does this library ship with your software?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to read these links:

- [Introduction to Mono - your first Mono app](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9407/Introduction-to-Mono-Your-first-Mono-app)
- [Answer of running
  application in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13103418/4519059)
- [Mono Project Site](http://www.mono-project.com/)